# Mysterious variable "URL" inside inline event handlers

Tags: javascript, html

In the following code, what would you see in the alert dialog when you click on **click here**?

```
<script>
URL = 'hello' ;
document.write(URL) ;
</script>
<div onclick="alert(URL)">click here</div>
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zH6X7/2/)

I was so sure the answer would be "hello" that I did not even care to try it.
But what I actually see is the url of the current page (tested on Chrome, Firefox and IE9).

Why is this `URL` varaible defined inside inline event handlers?
Why does it take precedence over my own variable?
Where can I find documentation about this behaviour?

---

**Follow-up**

Is this meant to happen only inside inline event handlers?
What's the motivation for something like this?

---

**Follow-up 2**

I did more testing on old browsers and this behavior seems to be an trace from ancient times. I verified it on the following browsers:

- Mozilla 1.0.1
- Firefox 2.0.0.6
- IExplorer 6.0
- Nestscape 8.1.2
- Opera 9.02

Which means this URL variable is definately not the experimental `window.URL` function/constructor. It is a string and it exist only inside inline event handlers.

Comment: If it's not the special `window.URL`, then why would the behavior change (as it does) if you change to another variable name (such as lower-case `url`)?

Comment: @TedHopp because inside an inline event handler the variable `URL` has a special meaning, it's not the same as `windows.URL`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<strike>The variable `window.URL` (that is, the global variable `URL`) is special. (Change your script to use another name, such as `url`, and it will behave as you originally expected.) Some documentation about `URL` can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL). Note that browsers that do *not* support `URL` will not behave in this unexpected way.</strike>

Well, the above was not quite right. There are two `URL` variables in play here. When the script runs, it overwrites (or creates) `window.URL`, which is then written to the document. (Note that your code wipes out `window.URL`, so once your script runs, you no longer can do things like `var n = new URL(...);` in browsers that supported that technology.)

On the other hand, when the `<div>` is created, the `onclick` handler attribute value is converted to the function:

```
function() {
    alert(URL);
}
```

The important thing, which explains the behavior) is that the conversion from a string to a function is carried out in the context of `document`. Thus the `URL` in this function refers to `document.URL`. (The `document.URL` property is described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.URL).) You can verify this by exercising the following:

```
<script>
URL = 'hello' ;
document.write(URL);
</script>
<div onclick="alert(URL === document.URL)">click here</div>
```

Comment: 99% of the browser market already behabes in this unexpected way

Comment: @GetFree - I don't know about 99%. There are plenty of browsers that do not support URL, including IE9, old mobile browsers, and any number of other platforms. (IE9's share of the market dropped below 10% in 2013; I doubt that it's fallen below 1% already.)

Comment: I tried in IE8 and IE9 and they both behave in this way. So I would say Chrome + Firefox + IE8+ is pretty much 99% of the market share.

Comment: @GetFree - Interesting. The Mozilla docs say that it is only supported in IE10+. I suppose you can't believe everything you read. :)

Comment: I'll have to downvote this. This URL variable is not the new `window.URL` object you mention. The variable is of type `string` and exist only inside inline event handlers (I haven't detected it anywhere else yet)

Comment: @GetFree - Without a local `var URL` declaration inside the event handler, the variable `URL` is a global variable reference. You can open up the console and see that `URL` (or `window.URL`) is defined. In Chrome it is reported as: "`function URL() { [native code] }`".

Comment: @GetFree - Also, if your analysis is correct, how do you explain the behavior OP reported (not to mention the change in this behavior if you change to another variable name)?

Comment: [This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zH6X7/6/) should clarify what I say. Inside an inline event handler the name `URL` alone has a special meaning.

Comment: @GetFree - You were right about the special nature of `window.URL` being irrelevant. I dug into what's happening a bit more and updated my answer.

Comment: Oh my... so this problem is going to happen also with the variables `write`, `all`, `cookie` and so many others. What a mess... and somehow I manage to web-develop for 15 years without ever encountering this problem. I guess I don't use global variables very often.

Comment: @GetFree - As Douglas Crockford says, [Global variables are evil](http://yuiblog.com/blog/2006/06/01/global-domination/) :). If I need global variables, I typically pick a single global variable name that I know will not cause problems and use it as a namespace: I hang all my other "global" variables as properties of the namespace. (So instead of using a global variable `a`, I define `GLOBALS = {}` and then use `GLOBALS.a`.)